ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nvcc_plugin'
i m trying to work on cuda c on colab ive followed the whole process setting up cuda c the only problem im getting is loading the extension
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nvcc_plugin'

i try searching but didnt find any reasonable solution

thanks for the solution ive tried it but !pip install nvcc4jupyter and for loading extension %load_ext nvcc4jupyter this worked for me

try running !pip install nvcc_plugin or if that fails, pip install nvcc4jupyter==1.0.0
